# Reading iso-8859-1 rss feed C# WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, encoding, rss, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to read a rss feed which uses the iso-8859-1 encoding.

I can get all elements fine, the problem is when I put it in a textblock it will not show all characters. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. i've tried a few solutions I found on google but this didn't work for me. I must be missing something.. It's also the first time I really work with anything other than utf-16. I never had to convert anything before.

The app works as follows I downloadstring async(WebClient). So when that is called I get a string containing the complete rss feed.

I have tried getting the bytes, then encoding.convert.. But I must be missing something.

Like this is a sample

```
        WebClient RSS = new WebClient();
        RSS.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        RSS.DownloadStringCompleted += new         DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(RSS_DSC);
        RSS.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("some rss feed"));


public void RSS_DSC(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs args)
    {

        _xml = XElement.Parse(args.Result);
        foreach(XElement item in _xml.Elements("channel").Elements("item"))
                {
                   feeditem.title = item.Element("title").Value;
                      // + all other items 

                }
    }
```

I've tried this aswell

```
private void RSS_ORC(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

        Stream ez = args.Result;

        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(ez, e);
        XElement _xml = _xml = XElement.Parse(rdr.ReadToEnd());
        feedlist = new List<Code.NewsItem>();

        XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
        foreach (XElement item in _xml.Elements("channel").Elements("item"))
        {

            Code.NewsItem feeditem = new Code.NewsItem();
            feeditem.title = item.Element("title").Value;
            feeditem.description = item.Element("description").Value;
            feeditem.pubdate = item.Element("pubDate").Value;
            feeditem.author = item.Element(dc + "creator").Value;

            feedlist.Add(feeditem);
        }
        listBox1.ItemsSource = feedlist;
    }
```

Though titles contain characters that are not displayed well either. Like.. I can get the encoding to partially work. Instead of having these characters: the square with a question mark, a question mark or the singe square.

Don't get me wrong I'm a total beginner on this. But the solutions that has been posted on the web do not solve it for me.

Note that I removed the encoding part because it wasn't working :/
If someone would be able to help me that would be amazing.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify an encoding by setting encoding *before* calling `client.DownloadStringAsync`:

```
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
```

In your code sample you do not create the XML doc anywhere. Are some code missing? You should initialize it with something like:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load((string)args.Result);
```

Comment: Sorry, I left out some code. I do specify the encoding. And for xml i do it like this

   XElement _xml;
   _xml = XElement.Parse(args.Result);

Comment: 1. Update your question with complete code. 2. Are you sure that the returned string is iso8559-1?

Comment: Well it's specified in the rss source. So I guess so?

Comment: @jgauffin.  Windows Phone 7 does not include the iso-8859-1 encoding.

Comment: All I can find in MSDN is that **Silverlight** (including the Windows Phone version) do not support all encodings. But MSDN also states that an exception will be thrown if the specified encoding is not supported.

Comment: Yes. I still don't know how to solve it btw... I'll try with doing a readasync

Comment: @jgauffin:  The MSDN documentation for `GetEncoding` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c(v=VS.95).aspx list the valid values for encoding name that may be passed to `GetEncoding`.  Also this topic in MSDN adds some detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903960(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: Are the **Silverlight** framework version the only version that can run on a Windows Phone 7? I thought that the Compact Framework works for WP7?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones The confusing part is that there's no concrete line that says it's not supported, neither do they say it is. But using the generated file from the link to the blog, i get the same result as using getEncoding("ISO-8859-1") in the system.text namespace. And no exceptions are thrown... I must be doing it terribly wrong orsomething. But could you try to read a iso-8859-1 feed in wp7. And show me how it's done?

Comment: @Helpme:  The documentation for `GetEncoding` lists the only values that the name property allows.  As to using the generated file, I very suspect you are expecting to simply create an instance of the class much it creates, that is the encoding object you then use.  The existing `GetEncoding` will not be aware of it, you just don't use `GetEncoding` at all.

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, you can use:

```
    var myString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(feeditem.description);
```

This way every special character will be decode, you can then display `myString` correctly

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 and Silverlight does not support other encodings such as ISO-8859-1, they only support ASCII and the Unicode encoders.  For anything else you will need to use `OpenReadAsync`  to get a stream of bytes then apply your own implementation of an encoding.

This [blog](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator) might be helpful to you in creating one.

Comment: I would of sworn I came across an Article on MSDN that it was supported. Atleast it carried the wp7 logo. But since I can't find it anymore I'll follow your advise and read that blog. I'll let you know if it works out!

Comment: @helpme: see my latest comment on @jgauffin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

ISO-8859-1 most definitely is supported in WP7. It is the only one of the ISO-8859-* encodings that is. I use an XmlReader to deserialize RSS streams and UTF-* and ISO-8859-1 are the only encodings that are supported by that class (windows-* and ISO-8859-2 and above throw exceptions in the XmlReader c'tor).

Try using an XmlReader like this (without specifying the encoding):

```
 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
 {
     ...
 }
```

The XmlReader will get the encoding from the xml declaration in the stream.

You may still have problems displaying the upper half of the characters (above 0x80). I had this problem in feed me (my WP7 app) and used this little hack to fix things up:

```
    public static string EncodeHtml(string text)
    {
        if (text == null) return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder decodedText = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char value in text)
        {
            int i = (int)value;
            if (i > 127)
            {
                decodedText.Append(string.Format("&#{0};", i));
            }
            else
            {
                decodedText.Append(value);
            }
        }
        return decodedText.ToString();
    }
```

It only works in a WebBrowser control of course, but that is the only place that I ever saw an incorrect display.

Hope this helps,
Calum

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when needing to decode the rss xml. It's generic enough so that it will support all encryption types supported by .NET

```
        WebClient wcRSSFeeds = new WebClient();
        String rssContent;

        // Support for international chars
        Encoding encoding = wcRSSFeeds.Encoding;
        if (encoding != null)
        {
            encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding.BodyName);
        }
        else
        {
            encoding = Encoding.UTF8;  // set to standard if none given 
        }
        Stream stRSSFeeds = wcRSSFeeds.OpenRead(feedURL); // feedURL is a string eg, "http://blah.com"

        using (StreamReader srRSSFeeds = new StreamReader(stRSSFeeds, encoding, false))
        {
            rssContent = srRSSFeeds.ReadToEnd();
        }
```