# Reading ISO 8859 1 encoding, xml stream download with  webclient

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, encoding, webclient

I am trying to make a basic webclient call to get an xml stream for a post tracking app for WP7. It does work and I do get the xml but the problem is as I am living in Sweden we have special characters as å ö ä etc. and for these characters I only get a box with questionmark inside.

The xml file I want to get looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?> 
<pactrack version="2.0" date="Sat Jan 14 18:29:26 CET 2012" size="2125" lang="SE">
    <header>
        <noofparcelentries>1</noofparcelentries> 

...
```

So the encoding is ISO-8859-1 and i guess that is my problem. Been trying to read around here on the forum for a solution and some say that the format is supported while some not:
[Reading iso-8859-1 rss feed C# WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329959/reading-iso-8859-1-rss-feed-c-sharp-wp7)

I been trying to add differnt encodings to the client but nothing seems to help, my xml is missing the special symbols always. There is however a strange behavior that kinda freaks me out, if I add a wrong tracking number, and instead of numbers put in special characters I can  suddenly read some of the special characters,the xml I get from the server is an error message containing the tracking number, see below, but the xml definition is the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<pactrack version="2.0" date="Sat Jan 14 18:34:43 CET 2012" size="389" lang="SE" >
<header>
<noofparcelentries>1</noofparcelentries>
<noofuniqueparcels>1</noofuniqueparcels>
</header>
<body>
<parcel id="8538öööåå54248SE">  //I can read this road of xml suddenly
  <customerref></customerref>
  <internalstatus>0</internalstatus>
```

Anyone have any ideas? I am a beginner and totally lost by this problem so any help would be greatly appreciated! Is there any difference in the first xml and the second? It seems to me maybe I cant see special charters that are nested in nodes, can that be the problem?

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.UserState as string == "mobiforge")
        {
            txtStatus.Text = e.BytesReceived.ToString() + "bytes received.";
        }
    }

    public void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
        }
    }

    private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
       client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://server.logistik.posten.se/servlet/PacTrack?lang=SE&kolliid=85380954248SE"), "posten"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c%28VS.95%29.aspx), only these four encodings are supported in Silverlight:

> - utf-8 UTF8Encoding
> - utf-16 UnicodeEncoding (little-endian)
> - utf-16BE UnicodeEncoding (big-endian)
> - utf-16LE UnicodeEncoding (little-endian)

According to one of the answers in your link, the user has managed to get it to work with a slight tweak to the upper half of the characters. I assume that didn't work for you?

Instead of `DownloadStringAsync`, you could download the raw bytes (`OpenReadAsync`) and perform your own encoding on the raw bytes. [This program](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator) might help you get started with that aspect.

**Edit** - Noticed a comment at the bottom the MSDN page stating that `ISO-8859-1` is supported. What happens when you try this:

```
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://server.logistik.posten.se/servlet/PacTrack?lang=SE&kolliid=85380954248SE"), "posten");
```

Then, in your callback, read the data with the encoder.

```
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result, enc))
{
     var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
     Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Latin-1 is supported now. It wasn't originally (I used to have a custom encoding class for it). I think it was the beta SDKs, that didn't support it.

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your help, tried this but when I call client.OpenReadAsync it seem it gets no result and gives nothing to client_DownloadProgressChanged? Any suggestion why?                                                                                                                                     Claus, as I guess you are from the Nordic countries, have you experienced this before? I am still confused about the xml i recive why I actually can read the special characters when i get the error message...

Comment: There may be a chance that the `content-length` property isn't being sent by the server. You could use Fiddler to monitor the traffic to see what the request/responses are. Also, instead of `DownloadProgressChanged`, handle the `OpenReadCompleted` event and see if the stream is returned there.

Comment: Ok that got it with OpenReadCompleted my å ä ö atlast, when I read thorough on msdn that makes more sense to use. Many many thanks, was stuck for some hours with this today...  Regards Krst